# metadata error SP.FieldLookup

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, spfieldlookupvalue

*Arigato* is a lookup field. I would like to change its value. I got error with **FieldLookup**. Can you help me?
[image: Flow]

Comment: Can you please point out the error or add what error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update Lookup field, you have to use this format in the body:

```
'<LookupColumnName>Id':'<ID>'
```

You should use this: `'ArigatoId':'7'`

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works for me!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: I would have liked to... but it tells me: **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.**

Comment: That's vote on it, vote up needs at least 15 reputation. You could still accept the answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done! I didn't see the check mark.